# How to run flycheck synchronously and programmatically

Tags: flycheck, batch-mode

As part of some automated tests I'd like to include flycheck. However, I haven't found a way to invoke the checker programmatically and synchronously.

I've tried something like:

```
(progn
  (with-current-buffer (find-file "my-file.el")
    (flycheck-mode)
    (flycheck-list-errors)
    (sleep-for 5))
  (with-current-buffer "*Flycheck errors*"
    (when (string-match "\n" (buffer-string))
      (kill-emacs 1))))
```

But this doesn't seem reliable and doesn't result in any warnings even when `my-file.el` does trigger flycheck warnings.

Is there a recommended way to invoke flycheck synchronously?

Comment: I'd start with [`flycheck-buffer`](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/syntax-checks.html?highlight=flycheck-buffer#check-manually) and [An overview of Flycheck internals](https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/developer/developing.html#an-overview-of-flycheck-internals).